# How to add UILabel in TableView section

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have `UITableViewController` and I need to update `UILabel` value. `UITableView` contains sections. How do I create a UILabel in the left side of the TableView for update cell values. Because when I create `NSArray` it is updating the value in the table's right side, I am not able to add in xib for label in TableView. So please explain how to add a `UILabel`. It need to add or any other possibility.

Comment: I tried to improve the spelling and grammar of your question a bit but I don't really understand what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create an UILabel programmaticaly, code:

```
UILabel *myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 100, 200, 100)];
```

To display a text within UILabel use:
    myLabel.text = @"Lorem...";

And of course to add UILabel to your view:

```
[self.tableview addSubview:myLabel];
```

By default UILabel has a white background, you can remove the background or change the color easily:

```
myLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change from UITableViewCellStyleDefault to UITableViewCellStyleValue1 in `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

and do

`cell.detailTextLabel.text = [yourArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];`

[Docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html) of UITableViewCell. Good luck